# Update :( no voice

Tags: updates

don't mind updating but no voice, headphone is working but speaker isn't
[image: Photo]

I can't fix this ,No problem before updating
how can i get back it  THANKS!

Comment: Sometimes my speakers stop working if I reboot my computer after using Windows OS and the only fix I found is to shut down the computer and start it again instead of reboot again and again.